# AngularJS dashboard and authentification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, dashboard

I'm developing a very complicated dashboard app with AngularJS + Laravel5.2 that handles internal work of an organization. While it's good to load the app while user fills login form I don't want for someone to see internal app logic through angular controllers unless authenticated. Plus I have multiple user roles and I don't want users to load functions that they don't have access to. How can I achieve that?

Comment: make your app by following restfull api,and for authentication use oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial for user authentication using Angular and Laravel:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: consider converting this into a comment or elaborating it rather than just sharing a link in order to avoid downvoting